# Следующий код должен вывести начало и конец последовательностей чисел в массиве

Tags: java

здравствуйте вообщем я новичок самоучка делал задачку. Следующий код должен вывести начало и конец последовательностей чисел в массиве. Последовательности разделяются нолями. Компилятор почему то ругается на массивы ready_value и а.

```
public class home_class { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int[] massiv = {5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4, 0, 3, 54, 405, 541, 0, 1}; 
    doit.megos( massiv ); 
    for (int n = 0; n < doit.ready_value.length; n++) { 
    System.out.println( n ); 
    } 
  } 
} 

class doit { 
   static int e = 0; 
    static int r = 0; 
   static int t = 0; 
   static int i = 0; 
   static int ready_value[] = new [ 4 ]; 

   public static void megos(int[] massiv) { 
      for ( i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) { 
         if (massiv[ i ] == 0 & t == 0) { 
            doit.readyint( i - 1 ); 
            doit.readyint( i - r ); 
            r = 0; 
            t = 1; 
            } 
         r++; 
         doit.readyint( i ); 
       if (massiv[ i ] > 0) { 
       t = 0; 
     } 
   } 
} 

   public static void readyint(int index) { 
      ready_value[ e ] = index; //сохронение в массив 
      e++; 
      if (e == ready_value.length) { // увеличение массива 
        int[] a = new[ ready_value.length * 2 ]; 
        for (int q = 0; q < a.length; q++) { 
        a[ q ] = ready_value[ q ]; 
        ready_value = a; 

      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите создать новый массив с заданным размер, то нужно определять его в `new`

> int[] a = new int [ ready_value.length * 2 ];

```
public class home_class { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int[] massiv = {5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4, 0, 3, 54, 405, 541, 0, 1}; 
    doit.megos( massiv ); 
    for (int n = 0; n < doit.ready_value.length; n++) { 
    System.out.println( n ); 
    } 
  } 
} 

class doit { 
   static int e = 0; 
    static int r = 0; 
   static int t = 0; 
   static int i = 0; 
   static int ready_value[] = new int [ 4 ]; //надо определять что за массив вы создаёте

   public static void megos(int[] massiv) { 
      for ( i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) { 
         if (massiv[ i ] == 0 & t == 0) { 
            doit.readyint( i - 1 ); 
            doit.readyint( i - r ); 
            r = 0; 
            t = 1; 
            } 
         r++; 
         doit.readyint( i ); 
       if (massiv[ i ] > 0) { 
       t = 0; 
     } 
   } 
} 

   public static void readyint(int index) { 
      ready_value[ e ] = index; //сохронение в массив 
      e++; 
      if (e == ready_value.length) { // увеличение массива 
        int[] a = new int [ ready_value.length * 2 ]; //надо определять что за массив вы создаёте
        for (int q = 0; q < a.length; q++) { 
        a[ q ] = ready_value[ q ]; 
        ready_value = a; 

      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

static int ready_value[] = new [ 4 ]; -- не верно

static int[]  ready_value = new int[ 4 ]; -- верно